# How to track the users have became fans of my facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I know there is a Facebook tool named insights, but, at the moment it does not give me the information I need.

I would like to create custom invitation code to track how many friend of a specific user have became the fans of my page.

Small example...

John becames fan of my page, I would like to undersand how many friends of John became fans of my page.

I do not know how to do that, but I must need to know how many users have become fans and by whom.

Is this possible with a Facebook page, or do I need to create an application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with *FQL* ([Facebook Query Language](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)) using the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/). What you're looking for is the `likes` attribute which can be obtained from the JSON returned by http://graph.facebook.com/yourusername.

Ofcourse you will need to do further queries to obtain things like how many friends of a specific user liked your page. Probably something along the lines of `SELECT ... FROM like WHERE object_id = yourpage` and I would imagine you'd need to link that to the `friend` table with something like `WHERE uid1 = friendid` to get their friends.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I did not understand if i can do it via Facebook Page, or I need to create a Facebook APPLICATION. Could you explain it? Thank you!